# Why is my 301 Redirect Causing Mixed Content Errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis

I have an ASP.Net MVC website running the Umbraco CMS. We're doing some modifications for SEO purposes. One of those includes lowercasing all of the URLs. I've setup an IIS URL redirect rule to do a 301 redirect on all incoming urls to the ToLower'd version of the URL. It's the default rule that IIS creates:

```
    <rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I have some additional rules as well (http => https, drop trailing slashes), but this seems to be the problem one.

As expected, this ToLower lowers all urls. Unfortunately this includes paths like:

```
    /Content/MySite/Theme/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

That, combined with the main page being served via HTTPS results in mixed content errors. Images still load with a warning, but scripts and stylesheets are blocked.

The only solution I can see is to go through my entire solution and manually lowercase every single URL. But that rather defeats the purpose of using a URL redirect. It's also crazy flaky because I'm guaranteed to miss some.

How can I change this rule, or add an additional one, to avoid these mixed content errors?

Answer (score 0):

It sound like not all of your content is being served over HTTPS to get the mixed content message.  Have you verified this using your web browser dev tools?
I'd also be interested in the dev tools network tab, and what status code you are getting back for the content that is not loading.

Comment: The content *is* served up via HTTPS. However, when IIS redirects the call from "/Content/MySite/Theme/css/bootstrap.min.css" to "/content/mysite/theme/css/bootstrap.min.css", that redirect is sent as HTTP, hence the mixed content warning. I need to force the redirect to respect the protocol, but I do not know how to do so.

Comment: Ok, so the http=>https rule isn't taking effect for the bootstrap file.  Do you have anything in this rule that says don't do this for CSS files or only do it for aspx for example?  I'm assuming this file is served up from the same website that has this rule on it.

Comment: Hrm, after more research, it looks like the https redirect wasn't actually targeting the .js files. Now that it is, I'm getting 404s. IE, the content isn't available to be served via https. Now the question becomes how do I enable IIS to serve that content via https.

Comment: Ok, if IIS is serving your pages over HTTPS then I doubt it is IIS that needs configuring as you have it serving your site on the port/protocol already.  It is the Umbraco involvement that I'm guessing at now.... the following link has a config setting right at the bottom for the app url, which you can specify https if you haven't already.  I'm not sure when it comes to Umbraco otherwise though, good luck your getting closer https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/config/umbracosettings/

Comment: I'm actually thinking the issue is our load balancer setup. IIS only ever serves up HTTP pages, and those are encrypted at the load balancer, which passes them on as HTTPS. I think the resource calls from the browser are coming in as HTTP to the load balancer, then getting passed as HTTP to the webserver, where they're transformed to HTTPS, which results in a 404. What needs to happen is for the load balancer to do the transformation rather than IIS. Perhaps the IIS HTTP -> HTTPS redirect rule is the wrong way to go and it should all be done at the load balancer.

Comment: Another idea....if an asset (image, script, etc.) is hard-coded into a plugin or theme, change it from ‘http://yourweb.com/assets/logo.png’ to ‘//yourweb.com/assets/logo.png’ - then it may take on the https of the page, worth a try depending on how you are referencing things.